# Writing a makefile using cmake

Tags: c++11, cmake

I have a directory structure as shown below:

```
HP_detectnet
-CMakeLists.txt
-include
        -cudaFont.h cudaMappedMemory.h cudaNormalize.h cudaUtility.h 
-detectnet-camera
                 -include
                         -Ndetectnet.h
                 -src
                      -Ndetectnet-camera.cpp
                 -CMakeLists.txt
```

I have added following code to the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project (HPdetectnet)

# The version number.
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++1y -Wall")
set_target_properties(detectnet_camera PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

#There are lots of scripts with cmake
#for finding external libraries. 
#see /usr/local/share/cmake-2.6/Modules/Find*.cmake for more examples
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

target_include_directories(detectnet_camera_main /include)
add_subdirectory(detectnet_camera)
```

and below code to `CMakeLists.txt` inside `detectnet-camera` directory:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

set_target_properties(detectnet_camera PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

add_executable(detectnet_camera Ndetectnet_camera.cpp)
target_link_libraries(detectnet_camera GLUT OpenGL)
```

While running "cmake" I get following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to:
  detectnet_camera


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Can someone please suggest where is it wrong???

Comment: The error message is clear: When `set_target_properties` is called, there is no target `detectnet_camera` - you create this target after. You should firstly call `add_executable(detectnet_camera Ndetectnet_camera.cpp)`, and only then adjust properties of the target.

Comment: Thanks, It works...

Comment: But after this i am getting one more error in CMakeLists.txt file of the subdirectory. 
CMake Error at detectnet_camera/CMakeLists.txt:7 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    Ndetectnet_camera.cpp

Tried adding "include_directories(/home/nidhi/HP_detectnet)" to CMakeLists.txt before add_executable() call.

Comment: Command `include_directories` affects only on searching for *header* files. But path to a source file should be specified explicitely in `add_executable` call. As your source file is located under `src/` subdirectory (relative to directory `detectnet-camera`, where your `CMakeLists.txt` file is), you should specify it as `src/Ndetectnet_camera.cpp`.

Comment: Thanks..It works now.